# Arrayed Curved Face Object Instancing Bug

Tags: modeling, modifiers, instances

I was studying some tank treads when I came across a bug with instancing the treads via a proxy plane, but when I array enough to get the curved portion of the nurbs path, the instanced treads show an odd behaviour where it gets launched off the path for some reason. Has anyone found what causes this and if there's a solution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yep, sorry I forgot to include the file, it should be available to download now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring back the origin of the object called *Tread_Flat* to its geometry

Comment: Thanks! I thought I'd done this already, seems I had accidentally moved the vertices in edit mode.